# Primitive recursive function, constructing a proof

Tags: computer-science, computability, recursion

I've came upon an example in the book that is not that clear to me.

The disparity function is proved to be primitive recursive in the following way:

$$disparity(x_0,x_1)=(x_0-x_1)-(x_1-x_0) 
= add(subtract(x_0,x_1),subtract(x_1,x_0) \\
= add(subtract(x_0,x_1), 
subtract(pr^1_2(x_0,x_1),pr^0_2 (x_0,x_1)))$$

where $subtract$ is defined as a subtraction for $subtract(x,y)=x-y$ where $y<x$ and it returns $0$ otherwise.

The question is why do we need to use the projection in the last subtraction operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you typed that in right?  I would think the final equivalence would be:

$$add((subtract(pr^0_2(x_0,x_1),pr^1_2 (x_0,x_1)),(subtract(pr^1_2(x_0,x_1),pr^0_2 (x_0,x_1)))$$

When we break down our primitive recursive function completely, the reason we write "$subtract(pr^1_2(x_0,x_1), pr^0_2(x_0,x_1))$" instead of just writing "$subtract(x_1, x_0)$" becomes more evident when we think of the $subtract$ function as its own function $f$. (I will assume we have the 2-ary $subtract$ function defined and will not break it down).

If we were to write it without projection functions, the proper but incorrect way would be:$$f(x_0,x_1)=subtract((x_0,x_1), (x_0,x_1))$$

Which is nonsensical. Writing it the correct way gets a little tricky because the subtraction function is itself a 2-ary function, yet our input has not been broken down from its 2-ary form into two separate 1-ary inputs. We cannot go from the 2-ary input $(x_0,x_1)$ of $f$ to two separate 1-ary inputs for the 2-ary $subtract$ without explanation. Thus the projection function takes our 2-ary input, rewrites it as two separate 1-ary inputs to but put back into our 2-ary subtraction function, as follows:

$$f(x_0,x_1) =subtract(pr^0_2(x_0,x_1),pr^1_2 (x_0,x_1)) $$

I hope that helped!